# C# Event listening methods

Tags: c#

I recently downloaded VS 2015 and when writing an event handler, it auto completes a generic method for you, but it does so differently that what I learned/used.

This is how I would normally write an event handler

```
Foo.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(SomeEvent);
```

But VS2015 auto completes a method stub like this

```
Foo.SomeEvent += Foo_SomeEvent;
```

Both can use

```
private void SomeEvent(object source, EventArgs e){

}
//or
private void Foo_SomeEvent(object source, EventArgs e){

}
```

Both work with no observable difference. Are there any?

Comment: There is no difference, one is a shortcut for the other.

Comment: In what way? Does the _ mean anything? Why would anyone ever write it in the first way?

Comment: No, the _ does not mean anything, by default the compiler constructs the event name using the format ObjectName_EventName, which has been a convention for a long time (since at least VS2008), with auto-generated properties in the designer (ie `Button1_Click`). Some people still write them out long-hand (usually veteran programmers who don't update) but when it comes to generated code, they are the same. Shortcut means that the compiler adds necessary code to create the "new SomeEventHandler" part, usually its referred to as "syntactic sugar".

Comment: Than you. Does that have a performance effect?

Comment: No, no performance effect, its the same code after its compiled.